# jquery no.conflict not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to use both jquery 1.4 and 2.0 i am using noconflict function but this code does not work.
document head is something like this

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>var jq142 = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and the jquery2.0 code is like this

```
<script>
     jq142(document).ready(function(){
       jq142('input').parent().next().hide();
       jq142('input').on('focus', function () {
       jq142(this).parent().next().show();
      });
       jq142('input').on('blur', function () {
       jq142(this).parent().next().hide(); 
      });
    });
</script>
```

is something wrong in this approach because i am unable to make it work.

Comment: what do you mean by not working? is there a error in the console

Comment: in which browser you have checked ??

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the noConflict statement after the second script has loaded. See the last example:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/